# What would the next step be in this integral problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to integrate the following $\int \frac {3x^2+x+5}{3x^2+x+4}dx$
what I can see is that i can substitute $3x^2+x+4$ for $u$ thus making my integral $\int \frac {u+1}{u}du$ this will give me $\int (1+\frac1u)du$ noe I am not sure do I integrate the 1 in here with respect to $dx$ or to $du$?

Comment: if $3x^2+x+5=u$ then what is $\mathcal d u$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: that would be $6x+1$ if I understand correctly

Comment: Your integral is not $\int(u+1)/u\ du$ !

Comment: yes but you miss the term $\mathcal d x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \frac {3x^2+x+5}{3x^2+x+4}dx=\int(1+\frac1{3x^2+x+4})dx=x+\int\frac{dx}{3x^2+x+4}.$$

Comment: So elegant I just could not see it. awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You correctly choose $u = 3x^2 + x + 4$, but make the incorrect substitution for $\mathrm{d}x$. You should use

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = 6x + 1 \Rightarrow \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{6x+1}.
\end{align}